# Quantum Algorithm to Solve a Maze

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, superposition

I am trying to understand the paper "Quantum Algorithm to Solve a Maze - Converting the Maze Problem into a Search Problem" by Debabrata Goswami and Niraj Kumar (here the reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4116). But I didn't get how the unitary matrix F for evaluating the fitness level of specific paths is working... How can we build such a unitary? Can someone explain how we calculate for a specific amplitude the corresponding fitness value and encode it to a specific qubit of the fitness register?